# Delphi cargar nodo completo con su contenido en un string

Tags: xml, delphi

Dado el siguiente xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Sistema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd">
    <Cabecera>
        <IDVersion>0.1</IDVersion>
        <Obligado>
            <NombreRazon>EMPRESA DE PRUEBA, S.A.</NombreRazon>
        </Obligado>
    </Cabecera>
    <RegistroAlta>
        <Registro>
            <Periodo>
                <Ejercicio>2023</Ejercicio>
                <PeriodoLiq>1T</PeriodoLiq>
            </Periodo>
            <IdFactura>
                <NumSerie>FR230001</NumSerie>
                <FechaExpedicion>31/01/2023</FechaExpedicion>
            </IdFactura>
            <TipoFactura>F2</TipoFactura>
            <FechaOperacion>31/01/2023</FechaOperacion>
            <DescripcionOperacion>VENTA MINORISTA</DescripcionOperacion>
            <Desglose>
                <DetalleDesglose>
                    <TipoImpositivo>4.00</TipoImpositivo>
                    <BaseImponibleOimporteNoSujeto>1.00</BaseImponibleOimporteNoSujeto>
                    <CuotaRepercutida>0.04</CuotaRepercutida>
                </DetalleDesglose>
                </Desglose>
                <ImporteTotal>1.04</ImporteTotal>
                <EncadenamientoFraAnterior>
                    <NumSerieFraAnterior>FR230001</NumSerieFraAnterior>
                    <FechaExpedicionFacturaAnterior>31/01/2023</FechaExpedicionFacturaAnterior>
                    <HuellaFacturaAnterior>9yYI6U89U3IUIQE345EUGWEBsd7EKFCBP9trtYUJSD0JFFKJKrtthAuysfadfWPE</HuellaFacturaAnterior>
                </EncadenamientoFraAnterior>
                <SistemaInformatico>
                    <Version>46.243.1</Version>
                    <NumeroInstalacion>45</NumeroInstalacion>
                    <TipoUsoSistema>01</TipoUsoSistema>
                </SistemaInformatico>
        </Registro>
        <DatosControl>
            <Huella>005948F5A441A56ABF584804036409719AB89892608FD708BAB8AE5088C896AD</Huella>
            <TipoHash>01</TipoHash>
            <FechaGenRegistro>31/07/2022</FechaGenRegistro>
            <HoraGenRegistro>09:00:07</HoraGenRegistro>
            <HusoHorarioGenRegistro>02</HusoHorarioGenRegistro>
        </DatosControl>
    </RegistroAlta>
</Sistema>
```

Necesitaría pasar el nodo completo < Registro > conteniendo hijos y valores < /Registro > incluidas sus etiquetas a un WideString a fin de calcular el hash de toda la cadena.
Esto sería bajo delphi7  con Windows 10 x64. La construcción esta en base a un TXMLDocument. ¿Cómo puedo extraer a widestring el nodo completo con sus hijos y valores para poder calcular el hash de ese string?

Por favor a ver si alguien me puede echar un cable, por más que he buscado en google, tutoriales y probadas opciones no he tenido éxito.
Gracias.

Este es el trozo de codigo en el que me pierdo totalmente y no carga los datos del nodo

```
procedure TGeneraFicherosEnXML.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  RegistroFacturacion: IXMLNode;
begin
  // LEYENDO EL VALOR DE LOS NODOS
  ListBox1.Items.Clear;
  XMLDocument1.LoadFromFile( ExtractFilePath( Application.ExeName ) + 'Fichero XML prueba.xml' );
  XMLDocument1.Active := True;

  RegistroFacturacion := XMLDocument1.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[0];
  RegistroFacturacion := XMLDocument1.ChildNodes.FindNode('RegistroFacturacion');
end;
```

Comment: Hola Ramiro, falta algo de información para poder responder a tu pregunta. Por ejemplo, la versión de Delphi que tienes a mano y el sistema operativo para el que vas a compilar puede hacer la diferencia sobre qué herramientas están disponibles y cuál es la representación interna de los strings en memoria. Por otro lado, la publicación contiene varias preguntas a la vez y la idea del diseño de StackOverflow es que contenga una pregunta específica. Si es como pasar el nodo a un string, está bien, esa sería la única pregunta, creo que habría que dejarlo claro. Para más información mira [ask].

Comment: Hola jachguate. Gracias por tus indicaciones. Ya he corregido el tema, ya que el único objetivo es extraer a widestring el nodo completo inclusive las etiquetas de apertura y cierre junto a todo el contenido hijos y valores, a fin de calcular el hash del widestring resultante.

Comment: De entrada, no me queda claro si tu dificultad está en extraer el nodo con todo su contenido, o si está en _pasarlo_ a un WideString. Por otro lado, tampoco entiendo por qué deshiciste parte de la edición que hice. Sugiero que aclares el tema y lamento no estar en capacidad de ayudarte, hace muchísimos años no trabajo con Delphi 7 o versiones donde las cadenas no eran UTF16, ni las tengo disponibles para hacer alguna prueba. Suerte encontrando la ayuda que buscas.

Comment: ¿Cómo puedo extraer a widestring el nodo completo con sus hijos y valores? Si deshice algo fue sin darme cuenta y te pido disculpas.

Comment: Si te puede servir una respuesta para Delphi moderno, dejame saber y con gusto la escribo. Solo pediría que dejes un trozo de código en la pregunta dónde ya se pueda asumir que el documento está cargado correctamente en una variable local XMLDocument. No está en mis manos ofrecerte ayuda directa con D7. Supongo, sin embargo, que D7 soportaría la asignación directa de un AnsiString a WideString, el problema puede ser que, si la propiedad del nodo es ANSI, en el ANSI se pierda algún caracter del XML original, que según dice viene en UTF-8. En Delphi moderno no hay ese riesgo porque todo es UTF.

Comment: Ahí lo tienes jachguate. Por supuesto que me valdria aunque fuese en Delphi moderno. Quizas me pueda ayudar en mi antigua versión de Delphi. No lo se, cualquier ayuda va a ser bien recibida. En mi versión de delphi he trabajado con AnsiString perfectamente. Cualdo hago comprobaciones del nodo, que pienso que he capturado no muestra nada.

Comment: jachguate, he tenido encuenta tus observaciones tomando buena nota de ellas. Si que veo que accedes partes del nodo sistema, buscando registroAlta y si esta asignado (existe) buscas el nodo Registro. Todo de una forma ordenada y que no probé en ningún momento, yo buscaba directamente el nodo Registro. En fin, no sabes lo agradecido que te puedo estar por que ¡¡Funciona!! Tengo que realizar pruebas con distintas variables para ver si me devuelve el mismo hash y algunas otras. La cuestión funciona, tengo que tener precaución y "te estoy super agradecido"

Comment: Hombre, enhorabuena poder ser de ayuda. Me alegra que todo vaya encaminado ahora. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iniciaré diciendo algunas observaciones:

- no aplicas ninguna conversión de codificación al momento de leer el archivo y eso me parece llamativo, pues en el XML de ejemplo que colocas especifica que su codificación es UTF-8. Asegúrate de que eso es correcto, pues UTF-8 no es equivalente a ANSI.
- No puedo ver la declaración de la variable XMLDocument1. Si es un componente que has botado en la forma, argumentaría que no veo la necesidad de hacer eso, menos de reutilizar el mismo componente para leer varios archivos. Sugeriría que lo muevas a una variable local, como voy a hacer yo en mi ejemplo.
- En el ejemplo buscas un nodo llamado `RegistroFacturacion` que no existe en el XML de ejemplo, yo me basaré en la estructura del ejemplo para escribir la respuesta.
- Después de llamar a [`LoadFromFile()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/Xml.XMLDoc.TXMLDocument.LoadFromFile) no hace falta hacer True la propiedad `Active`. La documentación dice:

  > Loads an XML document and **activates it**.
  >
  > Call `LoadFromFile` to load the XML document specified by `AFileName` and **set the `Active` property to True** so that you can examine or modify the document.

  El resaltado es mío.

Dicho esto, veamos primero como obtener el nodo de marras. En el ejemplo voy muy despacio, buscando nodo por nodo en la jerarquía y almacenando las referencias. En el código final quizás no sea necesario hacer esto, es un tema de balance entre legibilidad del código, comprensión del algoritmo y (muy en último lugar) desempeño.

```
var
  Doc: IXMLDocument;
  NodoSistema, NodoRegistroAlta, NodoRegistro: IXMLNode;
  ContenidoNodoRegistro: string;
begin
  Doc := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
  Doc.LoadFromFile(LaRutaDelArchivo);
  NodoSistema := Doc.DocumentElement;
  NodoregistroAlta := NodoSistema.ChildNodes.FindNode('RegistroAlta');
  if Assigned(NodoregistroAlta) then
  begin
    NodoRegistro := NodoRegistroAlta.ChildNodes.FindNode('Registro');
    if Assigned(NodoRegistro) then
    begin
      ContenidoNodoRegistro := NodoRegistro.XML;
      Memo2.Lines.Text := ContenidoNodoRegistro;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

En Delphi 2009 o superior, todas las variables de tipo `string` son UTF-16, y la declaración de la propiedad `IXMLNode.XML` es:

```
property XML: DOMString read GetXML;
```

Y DOMString está declarado así en la unidad `Xml.xmldom.pas`:

```
type
  DOMString = UnicodeString;
  {$EXTERNALSYM DOMString}
```

Por lo que no hay conversiones al hacer estas asignaciones. Te recomiendo visitar estas declaraciones en Delphi 7, dónde las variables de tipo `string` son cadenas de caracteres ANSI.

Tendrías una gran suerte si le propiedad XML te devolviera el contenido en Unicode o Widestring.

Si no, estoy suponiendo que puedes declarar una variable de tipo `WideString` y  la asignación de un string a dicha variable es permitida y va a realizar automáticamente la conversión de tipo.

Aún así, estás corriendo el riesgo de pérdida de información en caso de haber caracteres que no tienen representación en el código de página ANSI de tu programa, y dado que lo que quieres es calcular un hash, que este no coincida en caso de haber de estos caracteres en el XML.

No logro recordar si en Delphi 7 había algo equivalente a la clase [`TEncoding`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.SysUtils.TEncoding), pero si lo hay, te sugiero hacer uso de estas facilidades para asegurarte de hacer conversiones, en lo posible, sin pérdida de datos, o al menos, con las representaciones más cercanas posibles.

Una posible mejora al código sería utilizar *XPath* para realizar la búsqueda del nodo que nos interesa.

Podemos añadir la unidad `Xml.xmldom` a la cláusula `uses` y realizar la búsqueda de esta manera. Para *facilitar* el trabajo, utilizaré la función `selectNode()` que ha escrito *Ken White* en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5384230/255257) en StackOverflow en inglés:

```
function selectNode(xnRoot: IXmlNode; const nodePath: string): IXmlNode;
var
  intfSelect : IDomNodeSelect;
  dnResult : IDomNode;
  intfDocAccess : IXmlDocumentAccess;
  doc: TXmlDocument;
begin
  Result := nil;
  if not Assigned(xnRoot) or not Supports(xnRoot.DOMNode, IDomNodeSelect, intfSelect) then
    Exit;
  dnResult := intfSelect.selectNode(nodePath);
  if Assigned(dnResult) then
  begin
    if Supports(xnRoot.OwnerDocument, IXmlDocumentAccess, intfDocAccess) then
      doc := intfDocAccess.DocumentObject
    else
      doc := nil;
    Result := TXmlNode.Create(dnResult, nil, doc);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Doc: IXMLDocument;
  NodoRegistro: IXMLNode;
  ContenidoNodoRegistro: string;
begin
  Doc := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
  Doc.LoadFromFile(LaRutaDelArchivo);
  NodoRegistro := selectNode(Doc.DocumentElement, '/Sistema/RegistroAlta/Registro');
  if Assigned(NodoRegistro) then
   ..
```